# How does bash interpret embedded quotation marks in an expression?

Tags: bash

Given this bash statement:

```
config_file=""$(dirname "$0")"/config.sh"
```

Is the expression interpreted as:

```
"" + $(dirname "$0") + "/config.sh"
```

or as:

```
"$(dirname "$0")"/config.sh
```

What should be the "proper" way of writing the expression/statement?

Comment: are you open to do it with some lines or just one line?

Comment: @JRichardsz preferably one line only. but i'm also open to learn about the "multiple lines" approach if this is the "proper" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the first one. You can jump in and out of quotes within the same word and all the adjacent pieces are concatenated.

The leading `""` is removed, and the trailing `"/config.sh"` is equivalent to an unquoted `/config.sh` since it contains no special characters. The whole thing is therefore the same as:

```
config_file=$(dirname "$0")/config.sh
```

Comment: It's safe to remove the outer quotes because bash does not do word splitting or glob expansion in a variable assignment. In other contexts, you'd want to quote the command substitution.